# Using Comparable/Comparator with dependency

Tags: java, compare

I was asked to implement `Comparable` or `Compartor` for a certain class, lets call it `V`.
suppose I have a Collection or a Set (not sure yet, but I don't think it matters) of `V`s.

`V` has a method, to evaluate its "weight", lets call it `evaluateWeight(String data)`.
As you can understand, the weight depends on the input, `data` which given as an argument for `evaluateWeight`.

So, the comparison is dependent on this parameter, `data`.

One solution could be; adding a data-member which will contain the last weight calculation.
Is there another neat solution for this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Hard to answer that without more information. What is the use case? When do you need your class to be `Comparable`? Is the comparison expected to be based upon the last weight? You might run into trouble if you compare objects with mutable values...

Comment: You have a fundamental issue here. The value of a particular object should be entirely composed of it's internal state. Depending on external data to evaluate the value of the object would mean that the object's state is not complete. We need more information to determine how to help.

Comment: First, I should mention it's part of an assignment I've been given and not an actual real-world problem. The comparison is intended to be used for the cause of sorting the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have `data` as a field of the comparator.  Pass it in when you make the comparator.  Then when the comparator does its work, it can pass it into the `evaluateWeight` method of everything that it's comparing.

```
public class ComparatorWithData implements Comparator<V> {
    private String data;

    public ComparatorWithData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(V o1, V o2) {
        return o1.evaluateWeight(data).compareTo(o2.evaluateWeight(data));
    }
}
```

This example assumes, of course, that `evaluateWeight` returns something with a `compareTo` method.